# Why the need for a using-declaration naming a constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, using-declaration

Both paragraphs, 7.3.3.p1 and p3, in the C++11 Standard, make reference to a *using-declaration* naming a constructor. Why is this necessary? The code below shows that the base class `A`'s constructors are seen in the derived class `B` as expected.

```
class A
{
    int i;

    public:
    A() : i(0) {}
    A(int i) : i(i) {}
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
//  using A::A;
    A f1() { return A(); }
    A f2() { return A(1); }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    A a1 = b.f1();
    A a2 = b.f2();
}
```

If I comment out `using A::A;` above nothing changes in the program execution.

Comment: I think that's meant for using a non-default constructor from the parent class, such as `A(int i)` to construct a `B`.

Comment: @JoeZ I don't think you need a using-declaration for this.

Comment: Look for "inheriting constructor".

Comment: @user1042389:  See the example below.  I just tried this with g++ 4.8.0, at least.

Comment: It was only 4.8.0 or so that these were supported by GCC.

Comment: @Xeo Yes, "inheriting ctors" seem to answer the question. Tks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's meant for inheriting the *non-default* constructors from the parent class, which is `A(int i)` in this case.  Change your declaration in main like so:

```
int main()
{
    B b(42);  // Want to forward this to A::A(int)
    ...
}
```

Without the `using A::A` clause, you'll get the following compiler error (at least from g++ 4.8.0):

```
co.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
co.cpp:20:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘B::B(int)’
     B b(42);
           ^
co.cpp:20:11: note: candidates are:
co.cpp:10:7: note: B::B()
 class B : public A
       ^
co.cpp:10:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
co.cpp:10:7: note: constexpr B::B(const B&)
co.cpp:10:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const B&’
co.cpp:10:7: note: constexpr B::B(B&&)
co.cpp:10:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘B&&’
```

but if you add the `using A::A` declaration back, it compiles cleanly.  `b(42)` ends up calling `A::A(int i)`.

Comment: It's called "inheriting constructors"

Comment: Need more coffee.  I just s/forwarding/inheriting/ above.  Thanks.

Comment: @JoeZ Tried with VS2010 and GCC to no avail.

Comment: I needed to use g++ 4.80.  I used this command line: `g++-4.8.0 --std=c++11 co.cpp`.